# apt-get update only for a specific repository

Tags: apt, package-management, software-sources

When I add a PPA and I want to install some of its content, it is quite annoying to re-update all my apt list using `apt-get update`.

Is it instead possible to only sync the content of a given repository?

Comment: Starting from wily, you could just use `add-apt-repository -u`

Comment: There is no `-u` on Ubuntu (15.x) Vivid as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Treviño It isn't mentioned in the Wily manpage: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html Is it documented elsewhere?

Comment: @muru I think that has to be fixed, it's only mentioned on `add-apt-repository --help`. Please open a bug asking to fix the manpage.

Comment: @Treviño @muru FYI, the `-u` functionality was removed since 18.04. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/65245/apt-get-update-only-for-a-specific-repository/1132852#1132852

Answer (score 104, accepted):

yes, apt-get can do that, and can do it in a nice way.

1. Append following to `~/.bash_funcs`

   ```bash
   update-repo() {
       for source in "$@"; do
           sudo apt-get update -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist="sources.list.d/${source}" \
           -o Dir::Etc::sourceparts="-" -o APT::Get::List-Cleanup="0"    
       done
   }
   ```
2. Append following to `~/.bashrc`

   ```bash
   if [ -f $HOME/.bash_funcs ]; then
   .  $HOME/.bash_funcs
   fi
   ```
3. Append following to `~/.bash_completion`

   ```bash
   # Debian user-defined completion                             -*- shell-script -*-

   _ppa_lists(){
       local cur
       _init_completion || return

       COMPREPLY=( $( find /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ -name "*$cur*.list" \
   -exec basename {} \; 2> /dev/null ) )
       return 0
   } &&
   complete -F _ppa_lists update-repo
   ```
4. Then source the files

   ```bash
   . ~/.bashrc
   . ~/.bash_completion
   ```
5. Done and start to fire it

   ```bash
   update-repo <tab> <tab>
   ```

You can update a single ppa repository without having to update whole apt source, with implement of bash-completion.

Answer (score 55):

If the repository is configured in a specific file in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, say `myrepo.list`, you can update that single repository with the command:

```
sudo apt-get update -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist="sources.list.d/myrepo.list" \
    -o Dir::Etc::sourceparts="-" -o APT::Get::List-Cleanup="0"
```

Nevertheless this is not very convenient.
This can be simplified defining a bash function

```
update_repo() {
    sudo apt-get update -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist="sources.list.d/$1.list" \
        -o Dir::Etc::sourceparts="-" -o APT::Get::List-Cleanup="0"
}
```

so that you can simply run

```
update_repo myrepo
```

Comment: I've checked this again, but it doesn't work if then you want to install a package that has some unresolved dependency on another repository (also in the main archive)

Comment: can you explain what does '-' mean in sourceparts config?

Comment: I think '-' just a dummy way to tell `sourceparts` should not be used. See https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/master/apt-pkg/sourcelist.cc#L313 . I could be wrong though, couldn't find a proper doc explaining the '-'.

Answer (score 12):

Y PPA Manager comes with a command line tool called `update-ppa` that lets you update a single PPA.

For example:

```
sudo update-ppa ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
```

Also, when adding a PPA through Y PPA Manager, the PPA source is automatically updated (only for that PPA). In a future version, there's going to be a GUI to manually update single PPAs as well.

More information about Y PPA Manager, [HERE](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/07/y-ppa-manager-0087-released.html).

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager` then `sudo apt-get update` and finally `sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager`

Answer (score 9):

To update a specific repository, use `-o`, e.g.:

```
apt-get update -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist=/path/to/repo.list
```

Here is a one-liner updating only recently added apt repository

```
find /etc/apt/sources.list.d -type f -name '*.list' -exec sudo apt-get update -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist="{}" ';'
```

It's much quicker than updating all repositories, especially during VM provisioning after adding new.

Comment: I think this updates everything found in `/path/to`

Comment: @JohnBachir Exactly.

Answer (score 5):

[The `-u` option was added in 15.10](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/commit/?h=ubuntu/bionic&id=1e5fd76d711600230805a720ce9240b84985a9b6). From 15.10 to 17.10, you could use `-u` to automatically update only the specific repo you are adding:

`add-apt-repository -u my-ppa`

The silly thing is that this option was not added to `man` until 18.04 (it was documented in `add-apt-repository --help`, however). But in 18.04, this functionality was removed! (Again, not in `man`, but you can see in `add-apt-repository --help`).

In 18.04, the [update functionality was changed](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/commit/?h=ubuntu/bionic&id=c3e19efb51ed208b03ada75335f04df72e15c6b0) to always do a full `apt-get update` after `add-apt-repository`. The `-u` option was effectively removed. It remains there for legacy syntax, but it is always set to `options.update = False`. In 18.04, you do have the option of `-n, --no-update`, which is like the old behavior. But it's all or nothing, you cannot update a single repo since 18.04.

Answer (score -3):

One can also reduce the available choices to one single repository:

```
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe" > /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y ncftp
```

This may be radical, but it saves time and traffic, when running `apt-get` in a single-use container.
If you don't know what a single-use container is, please educate yourself before casting a vote...
because this is a correct and functional answer, which serves an actual purpose (saving time).