# Any way to skip the huge apt-cache-update everytime a repository is added?

Tags: 12.04, updates, add-apt-repository, apt-cache

I keep adding atleast one repository per day.! I like new stuff and to personalise my Ubuntu.

But now evertime I add a repository,the apt cache needs to be updated and its almost a 10-15min update everyday.! Moreover its a lot data consuming.

Is there any way or workaround so that the repository is updated in the apt-cache without updating other stuff?

Also,sometimes i do not wish to install some updates at the given point of time due to my bandwidth limitations.But then if i have to add a repository,the updates are all installed in the `sudo apt-get update` command..

Would like any help.

The bandwidth limit is actually a major issue for me.!

Thanx :)

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/65245/apt-get-update-only-for-a-specific-repository

Comment: @fossfreedom...well it says if a cache exists,it wont update.but in my case,it everytime does.even if i add 2 repos in succession within a span of 10 min!

Comment: a. Get off the main/US mirror to slow updates (that's updated every 30 min or so) b. "Cache" your desired repositories locally and then `apt-add-repository` them all on Sundays or something :p

Comment: @izx...how do i cache them? and should i then not use the janitor? so that the cache is not deleted? and will going off the main/us mirror give me less updates which might be actually necessary or is it something like less feature rich updates for apps will be done?(M a noob at the working of update process)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to get update from all the repositories at a time, uncheck them in `software sources`, and check them again when you really want to update from them.

https://askubuntu.com/a/27373/27559