# apt-get update specific list?

Tags: apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [apt-get update only for a specific repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65245/apt-get-update-only-for-a-specific-repository)

I'm working on a scripted install of something, and one of the parts is adding an Apache Bigtop repo and installing things from it. But having to do an apt-get update before installing is quite time consuming because of all of the other mirrors touched (and I do an update before hand to make sure the system has previously used tools in the script).

Is there either a way to do an update that doesn't update everything or a way to do an install and specify a repo/list that hasn't been updated?

Comment: If you want to put that as an answer, I will mark it as such.