# How to only apt-get update to update sources that haven't been updated recently, like today?

Tags: apt, updates

If I add a new repository, I have to run `apt-get update` before I can install packages from that source, of course. But it takes a few minutes for that to complete.

Is there an easy way to do something like tell it to only update sources that haven't been updated, say, today? Or in the past few minutes or something?

Comment: When you run 'apt-get update'  it doesn't download anything more than a cache of what packages and what versions of those packages are available. I don't believe there is any way to limit this. 'apt-get upgrade' is a different story however.

Comment: You can try updating only a specific repository. See http://askubuntu.com/q/65245/158442

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Y-PPA-Manager*, then you do not need to use `sudo apt-get update`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

1. via command-line with, eg:

   ```
   sudo update-ppa ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
   ```
2. via GUI:

   [image]

   [image]