# How to gpg check per repository

Tags: repository, gnupg

In RedHat or SUSE there is the option to enable or disable gpgcheck per repository name in the repo file.

Is there such an option in Ubuntu / Debian

- I want some repository to be checked and others not to.
- I know there is a way to ignore all but this question is exactly on how to ignore specific repositories while allow others
- The main goal is to run apt-get update and have only the one I've marked to check checked automatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I bypass/ignore the gpg signature checks of apt?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74345/how-do-i-bypass-ignore-the-gpg-signature-checks-of-apt)

Comment: probably combined with http://askubuntu.com/questions/65245/apt-get-update-only-for-a-specific-repository

Comment: sorry but this is not a duplicated. i do not want to create a special script that workaround it. just add is in the /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg or something like that. and to be honest i don't understand why i don't have that option in the source.list where i defined my repository i the first plate.

Comment: file a feature request

Comment: This is simply not how apt works, read for example https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt . It is not hard to sign a repository, and if the repository is not trusted it throws a warning (not an error). But I really do not see any situation in which one would like to suppress these warnings...

Comment: in order to install a package in environment where deb packages are check for signature via the release file its all or nothing. otherwise you will need to use the force yes or no-debsig or  APT::Get::AllowUnauthenticated "true" in order to make apt continue with the installation . its complicates the process need to run in order to simply install a package by using apt-get install .