# Disable automatic execution of apt update after running add-apt-repository on Ubuntu 18.X

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa

Okay so it's a feature that has been added to **Ubuntu 18.04** which automatically calls apt update after adding any PPA, sometimes it's a time saver as I don't have to run `sudo apt update` manually after adding a PPA. But sometimes it just pisses me off when I've to add multiple PPA's, and I've to wait for all the list updates after adding every single PPA.

Don't recommend "Can't you add multiple PPA by && ?", cause it's just pain.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Checking the help:

```
$ add-apt-repository --help
Usage: add-apt-repository <sourceline>
...
Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -m, --massive-debug   Print a lot of debug information to the command line
  -r, --remove          remove repository from sources.list.d directory
  -s, --enable-source   Allow downloading of the source packages from the
                        repository
  -y, --yes             Assume yes to all queries
  -n, --no-update       Do not update package cache after adding
  -u, --update          Update package cache after adding (legacy option)
  -k KEYSERVER, --keyserver=KEYSERVER
                        Legacy option, unused.
```

So:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -n ppa:...
```

Comment: Interesting! This `-n` switch is documented in `--help` but not `man add-apt-repository`  (on Ubuntu 18.04 anyway)

Comment: FYI, `-u` functionality has been removed since 18.04, despite the misleading `man` and `--help`. For details, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/65245/apt-get-update-only-for-a-specific-repository/1132852#1132852

Comment: The man page is still out of date in 2021. Wish contributing to changing it was as easy as a PR on Github

Comment: @oligofren [Planck's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_principle) ;)

Comment: [The manpage has been fixed in 21.04 at least](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html).