# Checking if an apt proxy exists

Tags: apt, proxy, docker, timeout

I setup an internal apt proxy, that is mostly used by my Docker containers for our development environment.

And thus in my `Dockerfile` I might have:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN echo 'Acquire::http::Proxy "http://<proxy-ip>:<proxy-port>/";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf
```

But this will work only when I build my Docker image inside the firewall.

Since I also want to build that Docker image on a cloud service host, that will not be able to access : nor it will make sense to do so, I thought I will put a check before configuring the apt-proxy client:

```
RUN <check-connection> http://<proxy-ip>:<proxy-port>/ && \
    echo 'Acquire::http::Proxy "http://<proxy-ip>:<proxy-port>/";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf
```

Since I am running this on a bare-bones `ubuntu` Docker image, when `apt` is not yet configured, I am somewhat limited in what the `<check-connection>` tool might be, to verify that `http://<proxy-ip>:<proxy-port>/` is responding as expected.

The best solution I got so far is to ask `apt` itself to check if it can connect:

```
apt -o Acquire::http::Proxy="http://<proxy-ip>:<proxy-port>/" update
```

This works pretty well when my proxy can respond, but takes a long time to fail if not.

The next thing I did is use the `timeout` utility to limit time to fail:

```
timeout 10 apt -o Acquire::http::Proxy="http://<proxy-ip>:<proxy-port>/" update
```

But the timeout (here 10 seconds) might be both too short and too long.

So my question is: **On a bare-bones Debian host (read Docker `ubuntu` image), what is the best (quickest and most robust) way to check if an apt-proxy is reachable?**

---

*Edit:* The original question mentioned a `debian:9` docker image, but for the sake of complying with the *ask-ubuntu*'s guidelines I tested it also with `ubuntu:latest`, got the same result, and updated the question.

Comment: "bear bone"? Do you mean [bare-bones](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bare-bones)? Or is it some new distro? Also, questions on distros other than Ubuntu (including Debian and other Debian derivatives) should be asked on [unix.se].

Comment: @muru, fixed. Thanks; Also the same question is for `ubuntu:latest`.

Comment: in that case, make it about `ubuntu:latest`. There's no guarantee that a Debian image and an Ubuntu image are going to have the same tools installed.

Comment: @muru, tested with `ubuntu` and updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can test if a TCP connection can be made to to a given host and port using bash:

```
bash -c 'read -t0 < /dev/tcp/<proxy-ip>/<proxy-port>'
```

This doesn't check if the service on the other end is a proxy, but merely if there is something listening on the other end.

Another option would be to [run `apt-get` for a single repository](https://askubuntu.com/q/65245/158442), for example, by writing `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) restricted` to a file and using it as the source.

Comment: As for the `/dev/tcp/...`, I first needed to `mknod /dev/tcp c 30 36`, and then `read -t0 < /dev/tcp/<proxy-ip>/<proxy-port>` it help me distinguish between `<port-ip>/<proxy-port>` and `<proxy-ip>/<other-port>`, but it hangs on `<other-ip>/<proxy-port>`.